# Asking for a zimmun

Tags: bentching, zimun

Why are there various different ways of reciting zimmun before birkat hamazon — why isn't there one set formula?

Comment: נברך שאכלנו משלו, ברוך שאכלנו משלו ובטובו חיינו is the whole obligatory text and is universally practiced across all communities to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @DoubleAA Where did the addendums come from ?

Comment: @shababnik, seemingly from Brachot 50a